# How to set up Node server for production on own machine?

Tags: linux, node.js, raspberry-pi

This must be a pretty basic thing to do, but I cannot find any good guide on how to do it on the internet. I only find how to set up a development environment for Node. I want to be able to forward my R-Pi's port 80 to my Node server, which I want to obviously listen on port 80.  How can I close the native port 80 so that I can let me Node server listen on that port.

Ultimately, I want to be able to access my pi from any remote location. I know how to set up a static IP and forward the port on my router, but now how do I allow Node into port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options. Either disable any other service running on port 80 and run Node with `sudo`. Or setup something like nginx to forward traffic from port 80 to your Node instance. To do that you can open a socket file with node and configure nginx similar to https://github.com/trevnorris/norrd/blob/master/conf/nginx.conf

Creating the socket is simple enough. It's as simple as

```
net.createServer(function(){}).listen('/path/to/file.sock');
```

I usually opt to spawn child processes for easier monitoring from the parent process, but use nginx to connect to each socket. For two reasons, one is it's easy to set route static content around the node process, and also because I prefer not to setup my own access privileges from scratch.